# UPDATE that field depends on condition of other table

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help with the following problem, when I make a sale in the ERP of the company it generates records of the sale in the table `sale_line` and logistics in the table `stock_move`; I would like to update a column in the table `stock_move`.

I have:

`sale_line`

```
id | description | quantity | state | type
15 | producto1   |    12    | done  | goods
```

`stock_move`

```
id | description | quantity | shipment      |  state
20 |  producto1  |     12   | sale line,15  |  done
21 |  producto1  |     12   |               |  draft
```

I need to update the table `stock_move` the column `state` when the table `sale_line.state = 'done'` and `sale_line.type = 'goods'`.

`stock_move`

```
id | description | quantity | shipment      |  state
20 |  producto1  |     12   | sale line,15  |  done
21 |  producto1  |     12   |               |  done
```

Comment: How do you know that `id` `21` of `stock_move` belongs to `id` `15` of `sale_line`?

Comment: Hi is for the field shipment in the table stock:_move

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are looking for something like this

```
update sale_move
set 
  "state" = 'done'
where exists (
  select 1 from sale_line 
  where
    sale_line."id" = regexp_substr("shipment", '[^,]+$') and
    sale_line."state" = 'done' and
    sale_line."type" = 'goods'
)
```